# Reed-Solomon in DVB-S/S2 and CCSDS

Tags: reed-solomon

What is the difference between implementation a Reed-Solomon code/encoder/decoder accorsing CCSDS standard and DVB?

I am not sure that the differences are the lenght of a codewords and rate.

Comment: do the symbols have the same length? I'd expect that DVB-S/S2 would need to account for longer burst errors, but I don't know the standard well enough by heart and would have to look that up as much as you do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes. I am looking for what is a difference in the implementation of the symbols have the same length according to these standards . I have read two standards, but no information was provided about it.

Comment: I don't understand – a standard doesn't specify the implementation. It only specifies the channel code. Don't mix up implementation and specification!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is it possible that I can have the same implementation of the RS for two standards but with the different specification ( length of CodeWord, virtual fill and so on)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was thinking that some differences should be. Because some engineers choose CCSDS and another ones  DVB

Comment: "implementation of the RS" makes no sense: you can implement an encoder or a decoder, but "the RS" is just a code – a mathematical description of what is what in a codeword; it doesn't *do* anything and hence is not something to implement. There's some decoder architectures that are flexible and can just be parameterized with different RS code specifications, yes, others are highly optimized for the one specific code. I really think you're confusing what the words "standard", "code", "encoder" and "decoder", and "implementation" mean!

Comment: Re: "some engineers choose CCSDS and another ones DVB" you mean "some engineers choose *the code specification from* CCSDS, others *the code specification* from DVB-S". These engineers do that after analyzing what their system needs from their channel coding, and then recognizing that either of these choices fits the needs of their system. Then, after having chosen the code, they figure out which kind of decoder for that code to implement.